# how to pass custom array list in one activity to another activity

Tags: android

I have a todolist application and ı cant pass customlist in one activity to another one.I  use data wrapper but when ı click add button program gives nullpointerexception.

this is AddItem.java

```
  okButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            ArrayList<Entry> itemList = new ArrayList<Entry>();

            task = editText1.getText().toString();
            priorityLevel = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
            status = toggleButton.getText().toString();

            int day = datePicker.getDayOfMonth();
            int month = datePicker.getMonth() + 1;
            int year = datePicker.getYear();

            date = day + "/" + month + "/" + year;





            itemList.add(new Entry(task, priorityLevel, date, status));

            Intent okIntent = new Intent();
            okIntent.putExtra("item",new DataWrapper(itemList));
            setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, okIntent);
            finish();
        }
    });
```

and MainActivity.java

```
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

        switch (requestCode) {
        case ADD_NOTE:
            Log.w("1", "one");

            DataWrapper dw = (DataWrapper) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("item");

            Log.w("2", "two");

            entryList = dw.getEntryList();

            Log.w("3", "three");

            //String extraName = AddItem.code;
            //ArrayList<Entry> list = data.getParcelableArrayListExtra(extraName);
            todoItems.addAll(entryList);

            Log.w("4", "four");

            todoArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            Log.w("5", "five");

            break;
```

Comment: if entry is a serializable object you can use intent.putExtra(String, Serializable). Check the documentation

Comment: your Entry and DataWrapper classes must implement either Parcelable or Serializable (Parcelable is recommended) to put in Intent.

Comment: yes,Both Entry and DataWrapper classes are serializable. ı use this line   okIntent.putExtra("item",new DataWrapper(itemList)); is ıt wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace

```
DataWrapper dw = (DataWrapper) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("item");
```

with

```
DataWrapper dw = (DataWrapper) data.getSerializableExtra("item");
```

in onActivityResult()...

Answer (score 1):

ArrayList implements Serializable

You can use intents

```
ArrayList<String> mylist = new ArrayList<String>();  
Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityName.this, Second.class);
intent.putStringArrayListExtra("key", mylist);
startActivity(intent);
```

To retrieve

```
Intent i = getIntent();  
ArrayList<String> list = i.getStringArrayListExtra("key");
```

Answer (score 1):

Implement Parcelable interface. http://bimbim.in/post/2010/09/27/Android-Passing-object-from-one-activity-to-another.aspx